# Wlan configuration when there is a portal login

Tags: debian, wifi, wlan

At a conference as we speak. Have a small embedded device running Debian that has no GUI. Trying to connect to confrence wifi which is open, i.e. no security, but has a type of web portal login page with a pre shared key. Because this is "upper layer", I don’t think there is anyway to "quickly" configure the interface to login to the portal. Or is there a way?

We can't put a GUI/web browser on this device and we have limited resources at this confrence.

Comment: What about a text based browser such as `lynx` or `links`?

Comment: I have a ready to use perl script which I use for such a situations, even with login cookie. I can post it if you care.
You will have to analyze html source of that portal login page to know the form submit link and form variables to POST.

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly, but...

1. Get the MAC address of the embedded device.
2. Power off the embedded device.
3. Change the MAC address of a linux laptop to the MAC of the embedded device.
4. Login to the portal via the linux laptop.
5. Power off the linux laptop.
6. Power on the embedded device.

I've used this for my Roku device with a web-portal login.  As always, YMMV.